# Removing sections of a large Java String (it contains HTML source)

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, replaceall

In my application I'm loading the HTML source of pages into a String. Within this HTML, I want to remove certain pieces of content that are *between* specific HTML comments.

For example:

```
//the entire String will be HTML source like this, of the entire page
<div id="someid">
    <a href="#">Some text</a>
    <!-- this_tag_start 123 -->
    <p> This text between the tags to be removed </p>
    <!-- this_tag_end 123 -->
    <a href="#">Some text</a>
</div>
```

That `this_tag_start 123` and the corresponding "end" one are generated by our server. The `123` number will vary.

In my program I have a String containing the entire HTML source. I want to remove the text between those two comment tags (it doesn't matter if the comment tags remain or not). These html comment tags can appear various times throughout the HTML source.

Right now I'm using this regex to remove the content:

```
htmlString = htmlString.replaceAll(
    "<!-- this_tag_start(.*?)<!-- this_tag_end[\\s\\d]+-->",""
    );
```

This works and correctly removes these comment tags and the content between the start and end tags. However, it doesn't feel like it's an elegant solution. There should be a better/faster way to do it, right?

If it matters, the String is generated by WebDriver's getPageSource() method.

Comment: @wheee did you take a look at his use of `#replaceAll`? It should be apparent what he wants.

Comment: If you don't have nested pairs, this looks like a legitimate way to do this.

Comment: I'd say this is a pretty elegant solution, also seems to be about as fast as you could hope for.

Comment: I believe your use of `replaceAll` is probably the best option. Although if you wanted to write your own method for pattern matching, here is a very useful algorithm: [Boyer-Moore-Horspool Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore%E2%80%93Horspool_algorithm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Elegance

> However, it doesn't feel like it's an elegant solution.

Here are two variations of the original regex:

#### *Variation 1*

```
(?s)\s*<!-- this_tag_start([\s\d]+)-->.+?<!-- this_tag_end\1-->\s*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iT6zQ9/2)

This variation uses a backreference for the id. One drawback I see is that this variation allows an id to be whitespaces only. As long as you control the comment this is not a concern.

#### *Variation 2*

```
(?s)\s*<!-- this_tag_start\s+(\d+)\s*-->.+?<!-- this_tag_end\s+\1\s*-->\s*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iT6zQ9/3)

This variation uses again a backreference for the id. However, it is more explicit on how the id is expected: one or more whitespaces, one or more digits followed by zero or more whitespaces.

### 2. Speed

> There should be a better/faster way to do it, right?

Internally, the `String#replaceAll` method calls `Pattern#compile`. Pattern compilation is notoriously known for being **slow**.

I would cache the result of the compilation for faster replacements.
Here is how to do it:

```
public class MyCrawler {
   // Compile once, run multiple times
   private static final Matcher COMMENT_REMOVER = Pattern.compile("the regex here...").matcher("");

   public void doCrawl() {
      String htmlString = loadHtmlSource();

      htmlString = COMMENT_REMOVER.reset(htmlString).replaceAll("");
   }

   ...
}
```